# Interpret CausalImpact summary

Tags: causality, causalimpact

What is Prediction(s.d.) in the summary output calculated based on? My understanding is that there are iterations done to get predictions of the counterfactual in the post-intervention period at each timestamp. So the sd is just the standard deviation of predictions? Can I use the standard deviation to select between models with different control variables?

[image]